# How to add multiple attributes to Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am constantly getting errors in Flutter.

```
Text(widget.time != null? "${widget.time!.count ?? 0} hours"
```

The above works perfectly.

However, I do not want to hardcode 'hours', as I will need it for translation. So, I am trying the following:

```
Text(widget.time != null? "${widget.time!.count ?? 0}" : (Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact) ?? ""),
```

But whatever I do, I am getting errors like:

> "Expected to find ')'

and

> "expected an identifier"

How can I resolve this?

I have the same case with:

```
List<Option> timeOptions = [
    Option(title: Text(Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact) ?? ""), isSelected: false, key: "free")
];
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
error: The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'.
```

And:

```
error: The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Comment: what are you using for `LocalizedKey` and `time`, can you describe theses two, and where you are using this code snippet?

Comment: What do you mean with 'what are you using'?

Comment: Can you define `LocalizedKey` and `time`?

Comment: It's not about the definition. LocalizedKey works on other pages and files, it's the combination of 'Option:" and Text that gives the error. LocalizedKey = in the localization directory and contains of multiple translations that all work, except for this one. This one is particularly annoying: Option(title: Text(Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact) ?? ""), isSelected: false, key: "free"),

Comment: it seems that you're missing an end ) Text(widget.time != null? "${widget.time!.count ?? 0}" : Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact) ?? ""),

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I guess it has something to do with the Option thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error :
You may defined `Option` like `Option({String title})`
So the construction should be like

```
List<Option> timeOptions = [
    Option(title: Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact ?? ""), isSelected: false, key: "free")
];
```

Or defined constructor like `Option({Widget title})`

For the second error :

You may coding like

````
  List<Option> timeOptions = [
      Option(title: Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact ?? ""), isSelected: false, key: "free")
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      ```
  }
````

Please change it inside `build`

````
  List<Option> timeOptions = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  timeOptions  = [
      Option(title: Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.locationContact ?? ""), isSelected: false, key: "free")
  ];
      ```
  }
````

Comment: Wow, amazing. This is all I needed. Thank you, Sam Chan!